# Obfuscated python code on github that I suspect to be malicious code

Tags: python, deobfuscation

I'm not too familiar or experienced with any programming languages, so I'm kinda stuck here and wondering if anything can be done. The basic gist is, I was browsing GitHub for a selfbot written in python for an application called discord. I wanted something to look off of to see if I could get an idea of what's going on. I ended up making a big mistake and forgot to check a script before I ran it. I was looking at it a bit later to find that it was obfuscated. A few hours afterwards, all 3 of my discord accounts were logged into via my account token, which bypasses 2fa and location login verification, and all 3 accounts were promptly locked by discord. None of the other python scripts I ran were obfuscated, so I figured this is the most likely scenario. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to deobfuscate the code to find out if this is the culprit and get it removed off of GitHub.

Here is the website it was obfuscated with.

https://development-tools.net/python-obfuscator/

Had to post the code here because it exceeded the character limit for StackOverflow.

https://zerobin.net/?806880066f5b7356#wyixWYKBCtGhAThmhM4XSwGqVkeXqTaG744nENY/LpA=

Here is the github repo

https://github.com/zVilao/Luxuria-SelfBot-Nuker-Discord

Comment: where is the github repo with the code?

Comment: I think this might be more of a question for github, if you flag something as a potential virus they'll probably have to look into it.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Unfortunately you've learned the hard way about running code you don't understand, and I'm sorry that happened to you.

Comment: Unless it's a submission to an obfuscation contest, the encoded values and `eval`S are a dead giveaway that this isn't something you want to run without analyzing what it's going to do.
The variables `magic`, `love`, `god` and `destiny` are almost certainly base64 encoded values. You could decode the values to get an idea of what they represent.

Comment: @Ryan I just want to clarify that this probably isn't a virus per se since viruses replicate, and there's no indication of that here. From looking at the commands it seems to be just generally destructive.

Comment: Check this: https://pastebin.com/MMuC1C8B

Comment: Another part: https://pastebin.com/tkURTe2K

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I should warn you: where the code you're dealing with is probably malicious, **don't trust any link in the chain** - not the obfuscation site, not even me. Verify everything yourself.

---

It looks like you can simply replace the `eval(compile())` in the last line with `print()` to get the deobfuscated code back, **but** there are obfuscated `eval`s in the preceding line, which could potentially be malicious.

---

#### Doing it manually

I'll use some real simple example code:

```py
print('foobar')
```

Uploading it to the site yields 8 lines of obfuscated Python code, as we would expect. To be safe, I'm not going to post it here in its entirety, only one piece at a time.

First there are some strings that contain `\x` escapes instead of the characters themselves. Let's extract them and see what they contain:

```
>>> joy = '\x72\x6f\x74\x31\x33'
>>> joy
'rot13'
>>> 
>>> '\x6d\x61\x67\x69\x63'
'magic'
>>> '\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x63\x73\x2e\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65'\
... '\x28\x6c\x6f\x76\x65\x2c\x20\x6a\x6f\x79\x29'
'codecs.decode(love, joy)'
>>> '\x67\x6f\x64'
'god'
>>> '\x63\x6f\x64\x65\x63\x73\x2e\x64\x65\x63\x6f\x64\x65'\
... '\x28\x64\x65\x73\x74\x69\x6e\x79\x2c\x20\x6a\x6f\x79\x29'
'codecs.decode(destiny, joy)'
>>> 
>>> '\x74\x72\x75\x73\x74'
'trust'
```

(I broke up two long lines to avoid hiding semicolons off the right margin.)

ROT13 is a basic letter-substitution cipher. Let's go ahead and decipher:

```
>>> love = 'DbW2Mi'
>>> destiny = 'pcPt=='
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.decode(love, joy)
'QoJ2Zv'
>>> codecs.decode(destiny, joy)
'cpCg=='
```

Now we can put that all together and decode it:

```
>>> magic = 'cHJpbn'
>>> god = 'b2Jhci'
>>> trust = magic + 'QoJ2Zv' + god + 'cpCg=='
>>> import base64
>>> base64.b64decode(trust)
b"print('foobar')\n"
```

So there's our original code back again, which is then compiled and evaluated in the last line.

Comment: The script is splitted in 2 parts, the first part gets info from pc and sends info to `` https://canary.discord.com/api/webhooks/853348950941630525/l8g9Fk3Q4c0a5SD9eMuRoGwgg3ExetSO35MECeG9csWRAh3Rn8MfSrWsZypbfXwdCd2b`` The second part i don't will check but if someone want check: https://pastebin.com/B2TmVcTZ Recomend only do static analysis, and start from line 502 to 506.

Comment: Thanks for the help and clarification. Exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it. Now that I have the webhook I can report the server ID to discord.